# ReactJS manipulate existing DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got this task during a job interview. I'm new to ReactJS so I couldn't find a proper solution.

I'm supposed to make something like bootstrap's toggle box:
[image example](http://bootsnipp.com/img/screenshots/4396ae51c0a824d6b8828cbbc8d920f396b993fa.png)

The important thing here is that the component should be invoked this way:

```
<ToggleBox header="The title goes here">
   The content of the toggle box
</ToggleBox>
```

I'm not sure but I think they mean that the invoking HTML code is attached to the DOM and not using React.render().

However, as far as I know, ReactJS isn't structured for rebuilding existing DOM, is there any workaround to accomplish this task?
Maybe I got it all wrong and by "invoking" they mean to use React.render()?

Thanks! :-)

Comment: What's `ToggleBox`? I don't understand how the question is related to the details you provided.

Comment: What is your question though? Now that you can have a go yourself at the problem (that isn't entirely clear), what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

The component would need to use `this.props.children`. You can look at the [documentation here](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html).

Here's an example:

```
var WithChildren = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var child = this.props.children;
        var header = this.props.header;
        return (
            <div>
                <div>{header}</div>
                <div>{child}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(<WithChildren header="Title goes here">Some content</WithChildren>, document.querySelector('.app'));
```

If you run that you will see `Some content` rendered. So all you would need is the extra markup and CSS to make it look like the image.

Comment: Thanks @gabo , but I think my explanation was not good enough. Your solution uses React.render. However, I'm supposed to do it from an existing DOM element.